# for loop combined with if statement in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I am working in R and I want to iterate over every unique/distinct name in this table and if A=="yes" | B=="yes" it should create another column C==TRUE for all entries with the same Name, else C==FALSE. I dont know how to combine a for loop with this if statement, I am always getting error messages, although it should be a simple task to do...

| Name | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jordan | yes | no |
| Pascal | yes | no |
| Nando | no | yes |
| Nando | no | no |
| Nico | no | no |
| Nico | no | no |

This should be the result:

| Name | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jordan | yes | no | TRUE |
| Pascal | yes | no | TRUE |
| Nando | no | yes | TRUE |
| Nando | no | no | TRUE |
| Nico | no | no | FALSE |
| Nico | no | no | FALSE |

Answer (score 0):

For-loops are often not needed in R.

```r
library(dplyr)

dat |>
        group_by(Name) |>
        mutate(C = if_else("yes" %in% c(A, B), TRUE, FALSE))
```

```r
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   Name [4]
#>   Name   A     B     C    
#>   <chr>  <chr> <chr> <lgl>
#> 1 Jordan yes   no    TRUE 
#> 2 Pascal yes   no    TRUE 
#> 3 Nando  no    yes   TRUE 
#> 4 Nando  no    no    TRUE 
#> 5 Nico   no    no    FALSE
#> 6 Nico   no    no    FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

R is a language that prefers vector calculations over loops, so the more common way in R would be

```
df <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Jordan","Pascal","Nando","Nando","Nico","Nico"),
  A = c("yes","yes","no","no","no","no"),
  B = c("no","no","yes","no","no","no")
)
df$C <- df$Name %in% df$Name[df$A == "yes" | df$B == "yes"]
```

This solution does not rely on any additional library.

If you feel strongly about looping, you could loop over `unique(df$Name)` or you could aggregate by `df$Name`, but all of those are much more involved and inefficient techniques.